# After set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT Production in Startup file IHostingEnvironment environment not getting updated

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, development-environment, production-environment

I am using ASP.NET Core WebSite which targets the .NET Framework 4.6.1 and what all way i tried to update Environment.

1.Updated in Project properties Debug ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT value as Production
2.Manually setting in launchSettings.json

```
 {
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iis": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost/MyApp",
      "sslPort": 0
    },
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:53996/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "Executable",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"
      }
    },
    "MyApp": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:53997/"
    }
  }
}
```

3.Windows Environment Variable

4.Setting through command prompt where csproj file is present.
 using the command `set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=PRODUCTION`

but after setting Production in above configuration setps still Enviroment is coming Development in Startup.cs file IHostingEnvironment.

I don't know i'm new Any other configuration i need to configure.

Any help.

**Edit:**

1.After Setting Windows Environment Variable under system level.

2.And the After while Restarting Computer System,Project is taking Environment Setting value whether it Production or Development.

Comment: I'm wondering why the `.NET FRAMEWORK 4.6.1` should care about the *ASPNET`CORE`_ENVIRONMENT*  ? Are you creating a ASP.NET classic website or a ASP.NET Core WebSite which targets the .NET Framework 4.6.1?

Comment: Yes i edited in the question,i'm using ASP.NET Core WebSite which targets the .NET Framework 4.6.1

Comment: Your configuration looks fine. The default is actually `Production` so something in your setup is somehow setting it to `Development`.

Comment: Could you please check the 'Supported target framework versions' section at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks#supported-target-framework-versions? I do not see .net core web app supports target framework 4.6.1.

Comment: @PrakashDale: It does. .NET Core 2.0+ supports .NET Standard 2.0+, and .NET Standard 2.0 works with .NET Framework 4.6.1+.